# pygame sprite not moving with self.rect.move_ip

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a game in pygame and I have got the basic drawing on the screen down, but user input is confusing me. I have a player class:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Player, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 25))
    self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

  def update(self, pressed_keys):
    if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
    if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
        self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
    if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
        self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
    if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
        self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)
    pygame.event.pump()
```

But whenever I press the keys down, nothing happens. This is the end of the script where the stuff gets drawn:

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    player.update(pressed_keys)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50))

    surf.fill((0, 0, 0))
    rect = surf.get_rect()

    screen.blit(player.surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

I don't know what is going on, but I can't find anything about this to fix it. Everything draws right, but nothing else.

Comment: typo: `screen.blit(player.surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))` needs to be `screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue: logical bug when bliting on screen

Inside your game-loop:

- `player.update` is *moving* the player by keys-pressed
- `blit` is drawing the player always fixed at the center `(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)` - **although player's position moved**

Thus your player stucks *visually*  centered on screen, although you moved it and its position (in `rect`) was changed by arrow-keys.

#### Debugging

Add some debugging `print` statements

- before the `blit` to monitor if players position moved after update: .
- after `blit` to monitor its return value as drawn rectangle

```
print("player's rect after update:", player.rect)
drawn_rect = screen.blit(player.surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
print("rect drawn by blit:", drawn_rect)
```

### Research

Suppose your intention with `blit` was to:

- center the player on the screen when drawn initially
- draw the player on the screen using `blit`

Let's consult PyGame docs for some support.

#### Centering a `Surface` object

Read the `Surface` docs on **how to center** with [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html?highlight=center#pygame.Surface.get_rect):

> You can pass keyword argument values to this function. These named values will be applied to the attributes of the Rect before it is returned. An example would be `mysurf.get_rect(center=(100, 100))` to create a rectangle for the Surface **centered at a given position**.

#### Using `blit`

From the docs on [`blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags=0)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html?highlight=dest#pygame.Surface.blit)

> Draws a `source` Surface onto this Surface. The draw can be positioned with the `dest` argument. The `dest` argument can either be a **pair of coordinates** representing the position of the upper left corner of the blit or a **Rect**

### Fix by design

[*Spawn*](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/spawning/info) the player at the initial position, e.g. `centered` (on the screen), during creation.

Then your game-loop has the [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) to `draw` the `player` on the `screen`.

#### Player: Center, Move, Draw

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self):
         super(Player, self).__init__()
         self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 25))
         self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
         self.rect = self.centered()  # spawn it centerd

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
         if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
             self.move(0, -5)
         if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
             self.move(0, 5)
         if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
             self.move(-5, 0)
         if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
             self.move(5, 0)
         pygame.event.pump()

## added some methods

    def centered():
        return self.surf.get_rect(center=(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)) 

    def move(x, y):
        self.rect.move_ip(x,y)

    def draw_on(surface):  # visitor-pattern
        surface.blit(self.surf, self.rect)
```

Note: added some functions to `Player`

- `centered` to position in the center within a constant screen dimension
- `move` to move the player with vector (x,y)
- `draw_on` to draw the player sprite/surface on a given surface like your `screen`

#### Draw

Then inside your game-loop replace:

```
    screen.blit(player.surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
```

by the new command:

```
    # new player is centered, moved player is located anywhere
    player.draw_on(screen)
```

Note: the [_visitor-pattern-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) changed statement to human-readable sentence in form `<subject>.<verb>(<object>)` and has one argument less than before (internalized).

### Bonus: Advice

Object-oriented design can be improved to enhance readability, ease testing and simplify usage:

1. control the player by functions like commanding actions
2. choose a simple game-language (domain terminology)
3. and use it for naming your abstractions (objects, functions, variables)

Examples: `Player`, `screen`, `move`, `centered`, `draw`, `_to`, `_on` (nouns, adjectives or verbs alike, with prepositions to express relation)

Often design-improvements make it easier to recognize logical bugs or to analyze the control flow during debugging - hopefully, like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have  to `blit` the player at the position stored in the `rect` attribute:

<s>`screen.blit(player.surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))`</s>

```py
screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
```